# Error reading from a file

Tags: readdir

Here is my code. 
myDir is created without any problem with permissions 755.

I could **opendir** without any problem.

Its **readdir** that is returning **NULL**?

```
   if(myvalue){
            Sint32 rtn=0;
            DIR *mydir;
            rtn = mkdir("myDir", _S_IREAD|_S_IWRITE|_S_IEXEC);
            if (rtn == -1) {
                    printf("\n**** Error mkdir : %s \n", strerror(errno));

            } else
                    printf("\n**** Success mkdir : %s \n", strerror(errno));
    errno = 0;

            mydir = opendir("myDir");

            if(mydir)
                    printf("\n**** Success opendir : %s \n", strerror(errno));
            else
                    printf("\n**** Error opendir : %s \n", strerror(errno));
    errno = 0;

            ent = readdir(mydir);

            if (ent == NULL)
                    printf("\n**** Error readdir : %s \n", strerror(errno));
            else
                    printf("\n**** Success readdir : %s \n", strerror(errno));

    }
```

And here the o/p

```
**** Success mkdir : No error
**** Success opendir : No error
**** Error readdir : No error
```

Comment: Is there another directory inside the directory that you are trying to open ?

Comment: No.  

$ ls -l myDir  

drwxr-xr-x+ 1 sl16 Domain Users         0 Jun  2 13:47 myDir  


$ ls -l myDir/  

total 0

Comment: From the man page its clear that the readdir will return the pointer only if there i a directory inside the current directory.Else it will return NULL to denote that there is no subsequent directory present

Comment: Test it with adding a directory and it should work

Comment: Added a directory 'tt' and a file 'ttt'. Still same results.  

$ ls -l myDir/
total 1
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 sl16 Domain Users 0 Jun  2 14:36 tt
-rw-r--r--  1 sl16 Domain Users 4 Jun  2 14:36 ttt

Answer (score 1):

This code assumes `readdir` always returns non-NULL for the first directory entry unless there has been an error.  This is true for POSIX systems because each directory contains the special entries `.` and `..` but isn't necessarily true on non-POXIX systems.

As the manual page for `readdir(3)` states,

> If the end of the directory stream is reached, NULL is returned and **errno** is not changed.  If an error occurs, NULL is returned and **errno** is set appropriately.

Since you don't know the value of **errno** at an arbitrary point in the program (some library functions might change it without returning an error code themselves), you'll have to set it to a known value which won't be set normally in case of an error before calling `readdir`.  Since all error numbers are positive integers, `0` would be a good choice:

```
errno = 0;
ent = readdir(mydir);
```

This way, you can discern the three possible outcomes from each other:

- `ent != NULL`: a directory entry has been read
- `ent == NULL && errno == 0`: no directory entry could be read, but it's not an error, so it's the end of the directory
- `ent == NULL && errno != 0`: an error has occurred

Answer (score 0):

From the man page

> If the end of the directory stream is reached, NULL is returned and errno is not changed. If an error occurs, NULL is returned and errno is set appropriately

Since there is no subsequent directory the function returns NULL and also errno is zero too.

Comment: The newly created directory 'myDir" is empty and the same code works in LInux. When I run the same code on VC, I see this problem?